# For-loop does not interpolate missing values in matrix using r

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, interpolation, na

I´m trying to interpolate NA-values in a matrix containing th first 2 columns with coordinates (x and y) and 24 columns with timedepended values. So I set up for loop which should interpolate the NA-values for each row on base of at least two values in each row (excluding the coordinates).
So I guess my problem is, that my for loop does not jump to the next row or always jumps to the first cell?

I use R-Studio Version 1.2.1335 and R-Version 3.4.4 on Windows 10

The complete matrix is up to row "layer.24" and column 492528

```
         x         y            layer.1   layer.2   layer.3   layer.4  
    [1,] 562201.9 5723273       8148      7031      7219      5824    
    [2,] 562463.6 5723273       NA        NA        NA        NA        
    [3,] 562725.3 5723273       4188      NA        NA        4200        
    [4,] 562987.0 5723273       4237      NA        NA        NA         
    [5,] 563248.7 5723273       3468      NA        5277      4888    
    [6,] 563510.5 5723273       3310      NA        5277      5095    

for (i in 1:length(matrix[,1]))
{
if (sum(is.na(matrix[i,3:26])>1)) 
{matrix[i,3:26] = imputeTS::na.interpolation(matrix[i,3:26])}
}
```

So I expected an interpolated matrix, except for row 4 in this example.

Comment: Solved the problem. Changed line "if (sum(is.na(matrix[i,3:26])>1))" to "if (sum(is.na(matrix[i,3:26]))<22)". So every row which has at least 2 values can be interpolated.

Comment: Except for row 4 or 3? **which should interpolate the NA-values for each row on base of at least two values in each row**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can work as follows(convert  to `data.frame`(named `df` here) first):

```
  to_replace <- df[apply(df, 1,function(x) sum(is.na(x))>2),]
   t(apply(to_replace,1,function(x) imputeTS::na.interpolation(x)))
             x       y layer.1 layer.2 layer.3 layer.4
    2 562463.6 5723273 5723273 5723273 5723273 5723273
    4 562987.0 5723273    4237    4237    4237    4237
```

You can store back the values to `to_replace`.

If you want those with less than two `NA`s, then:

```
to_replace <- df[apply(df, 1,function(x) sum(is.na(x))<2),]
 t(apply(to_replace,1,function(x) imputeTS::na.interpolation(x)))
         x       y layer.1 layer.2 layer.3 layer.4
1 562201.9 5723273    8148  7031.0    7219    5824
5 563248.7 5723273    3468  4372.5    5277    4888
6 563510.5 5723273    3310  4293.5    5277    5095
```